# Fill form with fpdm.php doesn't work with select value

Tags: php, forms, pdf, select, pdftk

this is my first question ever.

I have a form pdf that i need to fill with php, it works fine with fpdm. When I open the file in chrome or in Architect 4 even the dropdown list are filled but when I open the same file in Adobe Reader, everything is filled except the dropdown list.

Anyone have any thoughts about it ? I think maybe it's a conversion problem between FDF and PDF but i have really no idea on how to solve it.

EDIT :

```
    $fieldsI = array(
        /* ---------------- Beneficiaire 1 ----------------*/   
        'ZA1benefNom1'      => $InfosFormateur[0]['nom'],
        'ZA1benefPrenom1'   => $InfosFormateur[0]['prenom'],
         [...]
        'ZA4nature1' => 'H ', //strval('H'),
        'ZA4montant1' => strval($montant[$InfosFormateur[0]['IdProfil']])
);

 $pdf = new FPDM('pdf/das2/form2.pdf');
 $pdf->Load($fieldsI, true); // second parameter:  true if UTF-8
 $pdf->Merge();
```

I don't know where i can upload the result.

I have an other problem by the way, when I want to merge all my pdf filled, i try many solutions. I have one almost working :

```
public function combine_pdf($outputName,$fileArray)
    {
        $merged_pdf = "";
        foreach($fileArray as $filename){
            $merged_pdf .= " ".$filename;
        }
        exec("pdftk".$merged_pdf." cat output ".$outputName);
        header(sprintf('Location: %s', $outputName));
    }
```

But when i open the pdf generated in Adobe Pdf reader, everything is blank again.

Comment: Post a code snippet of what you're using, we need something to work off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. It's working !

You need pdftk on your server :

```
public function combine_pdf($outputName,$fileArray, $rep = "download/DAS/")
{
        $merged_pdf = "";
        foreach($fileArray as $filename){
            $merged_pdf .= " ".$filename;
        }
        exec("pdftk".$merged_pdf." cat output ".$rep."tmpfinal.pdf "); //merge all my filled pdf to 1 pdf
        exec("pdftk ".$rep."tmpfinal.pdf generate_fdf output ".$rep."final.fdf"); //generate a clean fdf from this pdf
        exec("pdftk ".$rep."tmpfinal.pdf fill_form ".$rep."final.fdf output ".$outputName); // then use the pdf as template filled by the fdf.

        header(sprintf('Location: %s', $outputName));
 }
```

I hope it will help someone